# Angular preselect option in a select input

Tags: angularjs, select

I'm a bit at a loss here. I have an array of teammembers. Each teammember has a roleId. I also have an array of roles. Each role has an id. I loop over the teammembers and, for each teammember, I display their name and a select with all roles. That works fine. I am unable to have the current teammember's role preselected in the select.

This is my data struct:

```
teamMembers = [
               {id,100,name:John,roleId,19},
               {id,101,name:Sue,roleId,20},
               ...
              ]
roles = [
          {id:19,name:'Administrator'},
          {id:20,name:'Superuser'},
          ...
        ]
```

html:

```
<tr ng-repeat="teamMember in data.team.MEMBERS">
    <td>
        {{teamMember.firstName}} {{teamMember.infix}} {{teamMember.lastName}}</td>
<td>
    <select
        ng-model="teamMember.roleId"
        ng-options="role.systemName for role in data.roles track by role.id">
    </select>
</td>
```

What I want is that initially the select displays the role where teamMember.roleId == role.id. Also, the 2 way databinding should update the teamMembr.roleId such that it always equals the currently selected role.id.

Is it possible to do this in Angular 1.5.0? If so, how?

Thank you for any tips!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this

```js
var app = angular.module("testApp", []);
app.controller('testCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.open = false;
 $scope.teamMembers = [{id:100,name:'John',roleId:19},{id:101,name:'Sue',roleId:20}];
$scope.roles = [{id:19,name:'Administrator'},{id:20,name:'Superuser'}];
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="teamMember in teamMembers">
    <td>
        {{teamMember.name}} </td>
<td>
    <select
        ng-model="teamMember.roleId"
        ng-options="role.id as role.name for role in roles">
    </select>
</td>
  </table>
   
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Shouldn't `role.systemName` be `role.name` in `ng-options`?
2. Use [`as`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) to bind to the `id` property of role:

   ```
   <select
       ng-model="teamMember.roleId"
       ng-options="role.id as role.name for role in data.roles track by role.id">
   </select>
   ```